# This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in // Update doesnot work

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok, I've been through hell cause of this error.

I'm just trying to develop something on Eclipse Luna using the ADT plug-in, but all the time I start a new project this error message comes in the activity_projectname.xml file.

I have already tried **Help > Install New Software** and then type **https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4** in the work with text box,no deal.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem as well (luna w/ ADT V23.0.6).  After trying several solutions (uninstall ADT & components, reinstall w/ https://dl.google.com/eplise/plugin/4.4 and https:/dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse, download zip and try to self configure,...)

I was about to uninstall luna and revert to kepler when I thought I'd try one last ditch attempt.  It's a hack solution, but a solution non the less:

Within the XML Graphic Layout editor, change the "Android version to use when rendering layouts" from 22 (in my case) to 19.  You'll find that option in the upper right - it's the Android icon.